# inputing multiple variables into a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

When i'm running this code in matlab, it is printing the g4 value into the array columns were g3 and its calculated value is suppose to be, as well as its own column. I was just wondering how to stop g4 being placed into g3's column and instead, print g3 and its value in the two arrays.

Cheers

```
v_meas = 0;
g1 = 1.09;
g2 = 0.9;
g3 = 0.93;
g4 = 0.85;
radius = 3.75;
K = 0.006;
m = g1;
g = g3;

for ii = 1 : 1 : 2
    v_meas = m*((radius^2)*pi)*K;
    ArrayOfDarceys(1,ii) = v_meas;
    ArrayOfGradients(1,ii) = m;
    v_meas = 0;
    m = g2;
    for jj = 3 : 1 : 4
         v_meas = g*((radius^2)*pi)*K;
         ArrayOfDarceys(1,jj) = v_meas;
         ArrayOfGradients(1,jj) = g;
         v_meas = 0;
         g = g4;
    end
end
ArrayOfDarceys
ArrayOfGradients
```

Comment: Could you post the output (please, no screenshots) as well and highlight where it has gone wrong, please...

Comment: The 3rd value in the arrayofgradients should be 0.93, not 0.85. Also the third value in the arrayofdarcys should be the value for 0.93, not 0,85.                                                                                          ArrayOfDarceys =

    0.2889    0.2386    0.2253    0.2253

ArrayOfGradients =

    1.0900    0.9000    0.8500    0.8500

Comment: Could you update the ***post***, please rather than the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you didn't intend to nest your for loops. Try this:

```
for ii = 1 : 1:  2
    v_meas = m*((radius^2)*pi)*K;
    ArrayOfDarceys(1,ii) = v_meas;
    ArrayOfGradients(1,ii) = m;
    v_meas = 0;
    m = g2;
end
for jj = 3 : 1: 4
     v_meas = g*((radius^2)*pi)*K;
     ArrayOfDarceys(1,jj) = v_meas;
     ArrayOfGradients(1,jj) = g;
     v_meas = 0;
     g = g4;
end
```

If I understand what you are trying to do you could significantly simplify your code though. There is, in fact, no need for any for loops:

```
ArrayofGradients = [1.09,0.9,0.93,0.85]
ArrayofDarceys = ArrayofGradients*((radius^2)*pi)*K
```

Comment: yes, I suspect this is the problem as well. +1 from here.